# export xml file to BSON using C#

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb, bson

I have an XML file. I would like to export it to BSON and then import the BSON from MongoDB. 
How do I convert XML to BSON with C#?

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried so far? Check this link out for how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should convert your XML contents to a memory object (instance of your class) and after serialize it to BSON...

something like that:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassType));
var data = serializer.Unseriliaze(XmlFilePath) as ClassType;
```

And after you should read to this link:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/